# How to decrease browser below 400px?

Tags: browser, responsive-design

This isn't exactly a coding question but I'm not sure what other stackexchange it should fit into.  It is related to responsive design development.

Safari and Chrome decrease in width to about 400px.  Firefox goes down to 90px.  Is there a way to get Safari and Chrome to decrease further in width?

If not, why is there a hard stop on those two browsers?

I'd like a further decrease for easier/better debugging of responsive sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome will decrease to as small as it can based on the extension icons contained in the omnibox-bar.  I'd suggest using a responsive testing tool such as ish:

http://bradfrostweb.com/demo/ish/

or an extension such as responsi

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/responsi/pgpclfmjhbalmpmpcghkpbfbkobhhnno

to test within chrome.

Comment: Yeah - it is.  Surprising to me this question didn't get a gazillion down votes and close requests.